# mysql, use condition in "where"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a database table like:

```
id name    date     price
1  a    2014-05-12   10
2  a    0000-00-00   20
3  a    2014-05-13   30
```

I want to search by date, and if the date exists, return the price of the date.
if the date does not exist, return the price of date 0000-00-00.

For example:

```
search by date:2014-05-12, return `10`
search by date:2014-05-20, return `30`
```

I have tried:

```
select price from table where (date=table.date or table.date='0000-00-00')
```

but it does not work.

How do I write the correct query?

Comment: Just use an `if` statement with PHP. Execute the query, and if the result returns 1 row, then the price is set from that row. Else, execute a query to grab the price for data 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that uses `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.price
from table t
where t.date in ('0000-00-00', @date)
order by t.date desc
limit 1;
```

Note that I changed the parameter name from `date` to `@date` to distinguish it from the column with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should table `table.field` (e.g. `table.date`), while in your example you have field.field (price.date).

Try:

```
select price from table where (table.date='{$date}' or table.date='0000-00-00')
```

Note that `$date` is a variable (assuming you use PHP). If you don't use PHP, you can't just write `date` as a variable here, but you can use `@date`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the field to be searched.Let it be $date_search.

```
if(!empty($date_search)) {
  $sql = 'select price from table where date ='.$date_search;
  mysql_query($sql);
}
else {
 $sql = 'select price from table where date ="0000-00-00"';
 mysql_query($sql);
}
```